# SUM() OVER With Condition Based on Current Sum Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table (TableA) that's somewhat like this:

```
Id  Type    TimeBlock   Value
1   1       1           100
2   1       1           150
3   2       1           100
4   1       1           1000
5   1       1           100
6   1       2           50
6   1       2           50
```

I'd like to be able to take the `SUM` of the Value column partitioning it by TimeBlock, however I'd like to only `SUM` the row based upon some condition. The condition is to only `SUM` the row if the current sum value 
is greater than or equal to the Value column

I assume the query would start with something like:

```
DECLARE @Amount int = 500;
SELECT *, @Amount - SUM (Value) OVER (PARTITION BY TimeBlock ORDER BY Id) AS Sum
FROM TableA
```

Which I'd like the result to look like:

```
Id  Type    TimeBlock   Value   Sum
1   1       1           100     400     (500 - 100)
2   1       1           150     250     (400 - 150)
3   2       1           1000    NULL    (This does not count since its of type = 2 and 250 < 1000)
4   1       1           1000    0       (250 - 1000 = -750 there its filled the @Amount so we'll leave it at 0)
5   1       1           100     NULL    (Since @Amount has been filled anything that comes after in this time block is NULL)
6   1       2           50      450     (500 - 50)
6   1       2           50      400     (450 - 50)
```

As you can see I need to be able to get the current values of the `SUM` function to be able to compare it to the Value column which I'm not so sure how to do. I'd like to be able to do something like

```
DECLARE @Amount int = 500;
SELECT *, @Amount - SUM (CASE WHEN Type = 2 AND SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY TimeBlock ORDER BY Id) < Value THEN 0 ELSE Value END) OVER (PARTITION BY TimeBlock ORDER BY Id) AS Sum
FROM TableA
```

**EDIT**
Type = 1 - sum the Value column no matter what
Type = 2 - only sum the Value column in the row if the current sum value is greater than or equal to the Value

Comment: Can you better articular the rules?  What does `type` have to do with anything?

Comment: I think the issue with type = 2 poses a problem that cannot be solved readily using cumulative sums.  A cursor is one option; another would be a recursive CTE (which would be iterating as well).  The problem occurs when you have multiple type = 2 -- whether the second one is included or not is not a simple formula, it depends on whether the first is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is based on the controversial *Running Sum Quirky Update* (described in more detail by Jeff Moden [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)), the following code will work:

```
-- prepare temporary table with required clustered index to control processing order
create table #t (
     Id         int not null primary key nonclustered
    ,Type       int not null
    ,TimeBlock  int not null
    ,Value      int not null

    ,RunningSum int null

    ,unique clustered (TimeBlock,Id)
);

-- load temporary table from data source, 
-- hard-coded data used for this example.
insert #t(Id, Type,TimeBlock,Value)
values
 (1, 1,  1,    100)
,(2, 1,  1,    150)
,(3, 2,  1,    100)
,(4, 1,  1,   1000)
,(5, 1,  1,    100)
,(6, 1,  2,     50)
,(7, 1,  2,     50);

go

declare @sum        int = 0
       ,@TimeBlock  int = -1;

update #t
    set @sum = case when TimeBlock <> @TimeBlock then 500 - Value
                    when Value > @sum            then @sum

                    else @sum - Value
                end
       ,@TimeBlock = TimeBlock
       ,RunningSum = @sum
from #t with (TABLOCKX)
where Type = 1
option (MAXDOP 1)
;

-- display results
select * from #t

drop table #t;
go
```

output:

```
Id          Type        TimeBlock   Value       RunningSum
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1           100         400
2           1           1           150         250
3           2           1           100         NULL
4           1           1           1000        250
5           1           1           100         150
6           1           2           50          450
7           1           2           50          400
```

Note particularly that this requires the clustered index to be identical to the ordering, and to ensure that this is not modified by other administrators the data is copied into a temporary table with the required clustered index. Also the **option (MAXDOP 1)** is set to ensure that no parallelization of the query is attempted by the optimizer, and the EXCLUSIVE lock is made so that (if a temporary table is not needed) that no modifications of the table can occur during processing.

**Update**: The *Quirky Update* is controversial because, although it is known to have worked since the early days of Sybase SQL Server, it relies on undocumented features of SQL Server that are not guaranteed to be supported in future versions.

Comment: Is there any reason why I should use this method over using a cursor?

Comment: @Ryan: Speed, pure and simple; check the performance testing described by Jeff Moden (originator of the term *RBAR*) in his article that I linked to. If your data volume is modest, say less than a few thousand rows, then a cursor might be just as suitable.

Comment: This ended up working well for me, however I had to change some of the logic with the CASE statement for the @sum variable